# Automatically supply yes to phx.new prompts

Tags: input, phoenix-framework, prompt, elixir-mix

I'm running [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelocg/phoenix/) containerized instance of Phoenix.

The [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/testing_controllers.html#content) says the following command can be run, but gives the error:

```sh
root@890ba3f1be37:/code# mix phx.new hello -y
** (Mix) Invalid option: -y
```

The environmental details are:

```sh
root@890ba3f1be37:/code# mix --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Mix 1.5.2
root@890ba3f1be37:/code# elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.5.2
root@890ba3f1be37:/code# mix phx.new --version
Phoenix v1.3.0
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't see any logic related to this in the mix task ([ref](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/802f381118a917c94bc39d9179e5d82865573c7a/installer/lib/mix/tasks/phx.new.ex#L120-L133)) so I guess the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link - is the best command then `yes | mix phx.new hello`?

Comment: I'd pipe `echo yes` instead as piping `yes` uses 100% CPU for me until the mix task finishes. Probably has something to do with how Erlang reads from stdin.

Comment: For the CPU analysis, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the documentation is incorrect as the mix task [unconditionally calls `Mix.shell.yes?`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/802f381118a917c94bc39d9179e5d82865573c7a/installer/lib/mix/tasks/phx.new.ex#L120-L133). You can instead pipe `echo yes` into `mix phx.new ...` to automatically respond to the prompt with yes.

```
echo yes | mix phx.new foo
```

Comment: Should this answer be referenced in a pull request for the erroneous documentation?